# Use permissions without a model

Tags: django, permissions

I have a django setup with no models, but I want to use the authentication / permission system to limit access to certain views. For that, I have created an empty model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Report(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view', "May view the reports")
        )
```

and added that permission to my view:

```
@login_required
@permission_required('report.view')
def index(request):
     ...
```

When logged in a `staff` user, it works, when logged in as a normal user, I get the login screen. But, in my admin panel, I do not see the permission, so I cannot give the normal user permission to view the reports. I tried to run `makemigrations`, but it says no changes detected.

How can I use an empty model just for permissions?

Comment: Maybe use report.view in permission_required decorator?

Comment: @AnshulSharma no. I still have no possibility to give anyone the permission. It doesn't show up in the admin panel.

Comment: There should definitely be migrations for this... have you run `makemigrations <your_app_name>` to force it to initialise migrations for the app? `makemigrations` on its own will not be enough.

Comment: @solarissmoke, did that, "No changes detected"

Comment: @solarissmoke oops, I put the model definition in the wrong `models.py` (in base instead of reports)

Comment: Can I ask why you didn't use django group or is_staff?

Comment: @seuling 'is_staff' is too big a gun. I want to give certain users access to specific parts of the site. I am using groups to do this now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no migration needed. What you need to do is to create the proper [ContentType](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#the-contenttype-model) entry, which is the field required by the [Permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.Permission) model.

Once you do:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Report)
```

... that does `get_or_create` behind the scenes and then you shall see a corresponding entry `report` as the content type when adding a permission.

Btw, if you're using this only to have the permissions, you can also add `abstract = True` to your Report model's `Meta` so that it doesn't create a database table for it. If you do this, you'll have to pass the keyword argument `for_concrete_model`. Here is an example code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models


# This is an abstract model that exists only so that we can create a ContentType
# for which can attach permissions to it.
# There is no database table created for it
class CustomPermissions(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True


def sync_custom_permissions():
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(
                                        CustomPermissions,
                                        for_concrete_model=False)

    permissions = [
        ("can_eat_pizza", "Can Eat Pizza"),
        ("can_deliver_pizza", "Can Deliver Pizza"),
        ("can_view_feature_flags", "Can View Feature Flags"),
        ("can_update_feature_flags", "Can Update Feature Flags"),
    ]

    for codename, name in permissions:
        Permission.objects.get_or_create(name=name,
                                         codename=codename,
                                         content_type=content_type)
```